How to Configure DE55 for Visa Network transaction
I need to configure DE#55 in Jmeter using ISO8583 plugin as shown below,
6201005F9F3303E0E0E0950500800000009F37049BADBCAB9F100706090A03A400009F26080123456789ABCDEF9F360200FF820200009C01009F1A0208269A030811059F02060000000012005F2A0208269F03060000000000008407A0000000031010

DE#55 XML config attached below,
   <isofieldpackager
          id="55"
          length="255"
          name="Integrated Circuit Card Related Data"
          class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLHBINARY"
          packager="org.jpos.tlv.packager.bertlv.BERTLVBinaryPackager"
          emitBitmap="false">
     <isofield id="0"
              name="DatasetID"
              length="4"
              pad="false"
              class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_NUMERIC"/>
  </isofieldpackager>

